# I can't receive e-mails sent from my website's e-mail form

Tags: php, html

I created a contact form for my website using php, I want the information entered in that form to be emailed to the address assigned to the form. But I can't receive the information. I don't know if there is any area i'm missing the code. The link of the contact form is this http://www.benliz.com.ng/contact%20form.html. I will appreciate all helps

Comment: Welcome to SO, please be a bit more specific when asking question: what have you tried, what do you expect, etc. See [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Please add code what have tried and are you running on localhost

Comment: Hi, please include your code in the question.

Comment: I tried pasting the code but I got a message that it exceeded numbers of characters to be pasted. Please how do I copy and paste the whole source code here?

Comment: First, you should edit your original question rather than adding the code as a comment. Second, make sure you're using the least amount of code possible to demonstrate the problem; we don't need to see your entire page (I suggest starting off with the function that sends mail and a few lines around how you call that function).

Comment: Any hints in the webserver error log?

Answer (score 0):

The big and immediate problem is that `mail.php` isn't in your web root, but your form action is looking for it there. Either adjust the path in your form or move the file to the web root.